# Possible bug: Wrong differentiation of ParametricFunction inside Parallelize?

Tags: parallelization, parametric-functions, broken-code

In the note [RootSearch problem when called from within ParallelDo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261792/rootsearch-problem-when-called-from-within-paralleldo)
I described the problem with Ted Ersek's `RootSearch` package and came to the conclusion that it is caused by the fact that the derivative with respect to the parameter from the `ParametricFunction`, which is obtained as a solution to the differential equation using the `ParametricNDSolve` function, is incorrectly calculated inside the `ParallelDo` loop.

The following example illustrates the problem. First, we solve an ordinary differential equation and formulate the result of the solution in the form of a function `ϕ1p`, which depends on the `z` coordinate and the parameters `β` and `Λ`. We also define the `ϕ1p1b` function as the derivative of the `ϕ1p` function with respect to the `β` parameter. This function and its numerical value at `β=0.4` will be compared with the `ϕ1p` derivative with respect to the `β` parameter, which we will calculate inside the `Do` and `ParallelDo` loops. This derivative within the cycles is denoted as `LHS1b`.

Inside the `Do` loop, the `ϕ1p1b` and `LHS1b` functions and their numerical values are the same. However, inside the `ParallelDo` loop, the resulting expression for the `LHS1b` function is gigantic, so the Short form is used to print it. Mathematica cannot calculate the numerical value of `LHS1b` at all.

```
Λs = {2, 5,
  10}; (* list of values for ParallelDo cycle *)
Km = 8; k = \[Infinity]; \[Mu] = 1; \[Nu] = 2; (* particular \
parameters from outer Do cycle not shown here *)

"Boundary condition at z=1: BC1[β_,K_,Λ_]" (* \
used in RootSearch *);
BC1[β_,
   K_, Λ_] = -(((-1 + K) (3 K^2 -
      2 β) β ϕ[1])/(
   2 (K^2 - β) (K^2 - β + K^2 Λ)));

"Equation to be solved: eqn=";
eqn = { (49 β (1 - (
         64 (8 - 7 z)^2 β (128 - (8 - 7 z)^2 β))/(512 -
           8 (8 - 7 z)^2 β)^2) ϕ[z] +
      1/(512 -
         8 (8 - 7 z)^2 β)^2 6272 β (32 (-1 +
            z) z^3 β^2 - z^4 β^2 +
         64 z^2 β (1 - 6 (-1 + z)^2 β) +
         1024 (-1 + z) z β (-1 + 2 (-1 + z)^2 β) +
         4096 (-2 + (-1 + z)^2 β - (-1 +
               z)^4 β^2)) ϕ[z] +
      56 (8 - 7 z) β Derivative[1][ϕ][z] +
      4 (64 - (8 - 7 z)^2 β +
         64 Λ) ϕ''[z]) ==
    0, ϕ[0] == 1,
   Derivative[1][ϕ][0] == (
    7 β (-3 + 2 β) ϕ[0])/(
    16 (-1 + β) (-1 + β - Λ))};

"Solution of ParametricNDSolve:";
sol1p = ParametricNDSolve[
   eqn, ϕ, {z, 0,
    1}, {{β, 0, 1}, {Λ, 1, 1000}}];
ϕ1p[z_, β_, Λ_] = ϕ[β, \
Λ][z] /. sol1p;
Print["ϕ1p[z,β,Λ]=", ϕ1p[
   z, β, Λ]];
ϕ1p1z[z_, β_, Λ_] =
 D[ϕ1p[z, β, Λ], z]
ϕ1p1b[z_, β_, Λ_] =
 D[ϕ1p[z, β, Λ], β]
(*=====================================================================*)


DistributeDefinitions[ϕ1p, ϕ1p1z, ϕ1p1b, BC1];
βm = 0.4;
"Do cycle ===================== "
Do[
  LHS[β_] = ϕ1p[1, β, Λm];
  Print["LHS[β]=", LHS[β],
   "\nϕ1p[1,β,Λm]=", ϕ1p[
    1, β, Λm]];

  LHS1b[β_] =
   D[ϕ1p[1, β, Λm], β];
  Print["LHS1b[β]=", Short[LHS1b[β], 3],
   "\nϕ1p1b[1,β,Λm]=", ϕ1p1b[
    1, β, Λm]];
  Print["LHS1b[βm]=", Short[LHS1b[βm], 3],
   "\nϕ1p1b[1,βm,Λm]=", ϕ1p1b[
    1, βm, Λm]];

  RHS[β_] = BC1[β, Km, Λm];
  Print["D[RHS[β],β]=", D[RHS[β], β]];
  , {Λm, Λs}
  ];

"ParallelDo cycle ============= "
ParallelDo[
  LHS[β_] = ϕ1p[1, β, Λm];
  Print["LHS[β]=", LHS[β],
   "\nϕ1p[1,β,Λm]=", ϕ1p[
    1, β, Λm]];

  LHS1b[β_] =
   D[ϕ1p[1, β, Λm], β];
  Print["LHS1b[β]=", Short[LHS1b[β], 3],
   "\nϕ1p1b[1,β,Λm]=", ϕ1p1b[
    1, β, Λm]];
  Print["LHS1b[βm]=", Short[LHS1b[βm], 3],
   "\nϕ1p1b[1,βm,Λm]=", ϕ1p1b[
    1, βm, Λm]];

  RHS[β_] = BC1[β, Km, Λm];
  Print["D[RHS[β],β]=", D[RHS[β], β]];
  , {Λm, Λs}
  ];
```

It seems to me that the described problem is a bug in the *Mathematica* system, although I admit that I am doing something wrong. **If so, where am I wrong?**

**EDIT #1:**
Same error occurs when computing derivative over coordinate `z`.